# Web-scraping using python

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, urllib

I am trying to extract data from this [website](https://portal.themlc.com/search), It is almost impossible to scrape as after any search it's not changing its URL.

I want to search based on *PUBLISHER IPI* *'00144443097'* and extract all data they have inside`class="items-container"`.

My code

```
quote_page = 'https://portal.themlc.com/search'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
name_box = soup.find('section', attrs={'class': 'items-container'})
name = name_box.text
print(name)
```

Here as the URL after search doesn't change it's not giving me any value.

After extracting values I want to sort them in pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the url doesn't change, you can use the developer tools to see if an api is being called. In this case there are two apis. One gives basic information about the writer and the other gives the information on the works. You can parse the json response however you wish from here.

Note: this a post, not a get

```
url = 'https://api.ptl.themlc.com/api/search/writer?page=1&limit=10'
payload = {'writerIpi': "00144443097"}
requests.post(url, json=payload).json()

url = 'https://api.ptl.themlc.com/api/search/work?page=1&limit=10'
payload = {'writerIpi': "00144443097"}
requests.post(url, json=payload).json()

url = 'https://api.ptl.themlc.com/api/search/publisher?page=1&limit=10'
payload = {"publisherIpi":"00144443097"}
requests.post(url, json=payload).json()

# this url gets the 161 works for the publisheripid you want.  it's convoluted, but you may be able to automate, but I used developer tools to find the right publisheripid
url = 'https://api.ptl.themlc.com/api/search/work?page=1&limit=10'
payload = {'publisherIpId': "7305902"}
requests.post(url, json=payload).json()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But in this case I can only extract based on Writer IPI and Work ID. Is there any way I can pull data using PUBLISHER IPI? I know there is no such API for publisher IPI but any other way around?

Comment: I tried to load the page with publisher IPI --> developer tool --> Network --> Fetch/XHR tab --> and copied the json response but that gives me all values for one page (10 values). Can I some how loop and get all responses?

Comment: sorry, i'm really unclear what you are asking. there's no 'publisher ipi' in the drop down to search. Can you edit your question with better examples?

Comment: [Screenshot for publisher ipi](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qilZK06LSDWsMeZ-1rGrTDqn-CqHmZbQ/view?usp=sharing)
Here, if you open WEBSTBURY MUSIC LTD dropdown there are 161 pages which I want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

To find the publisheripid, you need to open some of works within the author and look for the work endpoint. hopefully this image loads correctly

[image]